# got myquickconverter malware

Tags: malware

in a download site I got  hmyquickcoverter search engine that took over my desktop browser and I can not find its file to remove it! apparently it is a add revenue generator for them to direct ad click revenue to that site so they block my original browser and search engine. which was Firefox and Google. 
How do I get this Mal-ware off of my desktop? 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Check and disable its extension/add-on in all the browsers you opened meanwhile.

Comment: The myquickconverter is a malware, also known as browser hijacker. Usually, most of the search engines are legitimate and not harmful; however, most of the browser hijackers are developed with one goal, which is to generate advertising revenues. Innocent users will be tricked into clicking on displayed ads or advertising banners, and the owners of malware will earn a fee for every click. You may find a lot of reports about the myquickconverter and how it changes browser setting, installs unwanted toolbars without users’ consent,

Comment: thank you MichaelBay! it got it out of there. so simple. hope it does not return. we shall see.

Comment: Oh Peter, thank you for your Wiki contribution. Without such we wouldn't know what malware is.